# How to save am image of a screen using JOGL

Tags: opengl, jogl

I have Swing frame and some sprites drawn on it. I need to save this 2D scene as an image using JOGL but every tutorial I managed to find seems to be obsolete. I'm using JOGL 2.1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using Screenshot:

```
BufferedImage image = Screenshot.readToBufferedImage(width, height);
```

using AWTGLReadBufferUtil:

```
GLAutoDrawable glad = (GLAutoDrawable) event.getSource();
AWTGLReadBufferUtil glReadBufferUtil = new AWTGLReadBufferUtil(glad.getGLProfile(), false);
BufferedImage image = glReadBufferUtil.readPixelsToBufferedImage(glad.getGL(), true);
```

[AWTGLReadBufferUtil example source](http://worldwind31.arc.nasa.gov/svn/trunk/WorldWind/src/gov/nasa/worldwindx/examples/util/ScreenShotAction.java)

Comment: "deprecated" Screenshot method worked for me. But "improved" GLReadBufferUtil did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AWTGLReadBufferUtil](http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-next/javadoc/jogl/javadoc/com/jogamp/opengl/util/awt/AWTGLReadBufferUtil.html) or [Screenshot](http://com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.Screenshot) to do that. I advise you to look at the project jogl-demos on Github if you need an example. [Screenshot](http://com.jogamp.opengl.util.awt.Screenshot) was already available in JOGL 1 but is deprecated in JOGL 2.